# Exporting a PCB to the USA

Tags: pcb

I want to export an assembled PCB to the USA. Is there any label, for example FCC, that has to be on it in order to pass the customs?

Comment: Only the PC **board** as *component* or the PCB assembled as **module** or the PCB with components, but not assembled as **kit** or the PCB as **consumer appliance**? Is it an intentional radiator of electromagnetic waves? … This is a pretty gigantic question!

Comment: Is this just one PCBA?

Comment: The [HS code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonized_System). Eg: 853400, but the board might have a purpose that requires a different code. It's complicated. Ask your logistics guy.

Comment: @Jasen: Yes, it's just one PCBA.

Comment: @Marcus Müller: It's an assembled PCB that can drive LEDs and a small speaker. To use it, one needs to solder about 20 different pads. It's not intendent to radiate electromagnetic waves.

Comment: @Peter123 sounds like a kit to me, so you're selling components. That's a common way to circumvent the certification as consumer good.

Comment: @Marcus Müller: Thanks for your answer. So, would it be enough to include "kit" in the product description on the customs declaration?

Comment: Hm, probably not, because you're still importing technological goods, but this really depends on many factors – you'll want to talk to someone who does that for money, and share your profits with them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with *electronic design*

Answer (score 2):

in small quantites, even repeated small quantitues this is not required,  look at all the powersupply modules on ebay and amazon for example.

Comment: I was under the impression that a good part of these are in fact imported illegally. At least German "Zoll" regularly publishes reports of how many devices they stopped at the harbor, and that ranges from child-surveillance dolls to deadly and CE-label lacking supplies, IIRC.

Comment: at work we send PCBAs into USA in small quantities we have about 400 us clients (so have sent about 400)  have not done the CE UL or FCC  thing. and we always do a honest customs declaration,

Comment: May I guess this is b2b, and you sell components, not kits?

Comment: yeah b2b assembled devices.

Comment: So, it would make a difference if it was b2c I guess?

Comment: IIRC ther's an exemption for importing small numbers of devices in the FCC regulations - 5 or less than I think

Comment: I can confirm this (at least as of a few years ago). I used to send small batches (10-20) assembled PCBs to the USA a few times a year without any sort of FCC, UL, etc testing or labeling. It's not customs' job to know or check for product safety or if it complies with FCC rules.

Comment: @brhans: Did you send it from private person to private person or as b2b or b2c?

Comment: @Peter123 - b2b. i was operating a small business outside the USA and designed & built these boards for a company in the USA. I always included 'customs paperwork' in every shipment (a 'commercial invoice' which described the goods and gave them a value), but nothing else. If I remember correctly the description was something like "audio signal driver circuit board" or something along those lines.